# Starting service calls Application onCreate?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

If you provide an extended Application class, will onCreate be called when a Service is created, even if no Activity is brought to the foreground?

Comment: Start an application from a Service? Do you mean Activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Application.onCreate is called before anything in your package is instantiated.

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate%28%29):

> Called when the application is
>   starting, before any other application
>   objects have been created.
>   Implementations should be as quick as
>   possible (for example using lazy
>   initialization of state) since the
>   time spent in this function directly
>   impacts the performance of starting
>   the first activity, service, or
>   receiver in a process.

Comment: If starting service in it's own process it will call Application's onCreate. If it's called per process how to know which one..

Comment: This is how you get the current process name - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19631894/is-there-a-way-to-get-current-process-name-in-android