# Is there a way to get current process name in Android

Tags: android

I set an Android:process=":XX" for my particular activity to make it run in a separate process.
However when the new activity/process init, it will call my Application:onCreate() which contains some application level initialization.

I'm thinking of avoiding duplication initialization by checking current process name.

So is there an API available?

Thanks.

Comment: Would you consider changing the accepted answer to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55842542/238753)? It gets the process name the same way the the OS does, and I think it's faster and more reliable than the other answers. Thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

#### Get it from ActivityThread

In API 28+, you can call [`Application.getProcessName()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application#getProcessName()), which [is just a public wrapper](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/pie-release/core/java/android/app/Application.java#L202) around [`ActivityThread.currentProcessName()`](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/pie-release/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java#L1896).

On older platforms, just call [`ActivityThread.currentProcessName()`](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/pie-release/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java#L1896) directly.

Note that prior to API 18, [the method was incorrectly called `ActivityThread.currentPackageName()` but still in fact returned the *process* name](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/commit/b57a50bd16ce25db441da5c1b63d48721bb90687).

#### Example code

```
public static String getProcessName() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 28)
        return Application.getProcessName();

    // Using the same technique as Application.getProcessName() for older devices
    // Using reflection since ActivityThread is an internal API

    try {
        @SuppressLint("PrivateApi")
        Class<?> activityThread = Class.forName("android.app.ActivityThread");

        // Before API 18, the method was incorrectly named "currentPackageName", but it still returned the process name
        // See https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/commit/b57a50bd16ce25db441da5c1b63d48721bb90687
        String methodName = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18 ? "currentProcessName" : "currentPackageName";

        Method getProcessName = activityThread.getDeclaredMethod(methodName);
        return (String) getProcessName.invoke(null);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

#### Compatibility

Tested and working on

- Official emulator

  - 16
  - 17
  - 18
  - 19
  - 21
  - 22
  - 23
  - 24
  - 25
  - 26
  - 27
  - 28
  - Q beta 1
- Real devices

  - Motorola Moto G5 Plus running Android 8.1.0
  - Samsung Galaxy S5 running Android 6.0.1
  - Sony Xperia M running stock Android 7.1.1
  - Sony Xperia M running Sony Android 4.1.2

Answer (score 33):

Full code is

```
    String currentProcName = "";
    int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : manager.getRunningAppProcesses())
    {
        if (processInfo.pid == pid)
        {
            currentProcName = processInfo.processName;
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just be careful `manager.getRunningAppProcesses()` may return null (instead of an empty List as good design would dictate).

Comment: It can also be quite slow. Be warned.

Answer (score 29):

The ActivityManager solution contains a sneaky bug, particularly if you check your own process name from your Application object. Sometimes, the list returned from getRunningAppProcesses simply doesn't contain your own process, raising a peculiar existential issue.

The way I solve this is

```
    BufferedReader cmdlineReader = null;
    try {
        cmdlineReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            new FileInputStream(
                "/proc/" + android.os.Process.myPid() + "/cmdline"),
            "iso-8859-1"));
        int c;
        StringBuilder processName = new StringBuilder();
        while ((c = cmdlineReader.read()) > 0) {
            processName.append((char) c);
        }
        return processName.toString();
    } finally {
        if (cmdlineReader != null) {
            cmdlineReader.close();
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Please notice that this solution is much faster than going through the ActivityManager but does not work if the user is running Xposed or similar. In that case you might want to do the ActivityManager solution as a fallback strategy.

Comment: This is likely because your process is a remote service. If you call am.getRunningServices() and iterate through the RunningServiceInfo objects, you'll find your service process as well as the name you gave your process in the manifest in the .process field of the info object

Comment: What exactly happens that causes this to not work when the user runs Xposed?

Comment: Then /proc/your_pid/cmdline becomes unreadable even for yourself.

Comment: Thanks!  Did you ever find more info about the issue of Activity Manager not returning your process? Was Mike's suspicion above correct - that it was related to your service being in a separate process?

Comment: Yes, that was the case.

Comment: @DavidBurström I don't have a device running Xposed so I can check this my self - Does the whole `/proc/*` directory structure becomes unreadable? or only parts of it?

Comment: @MikeVenzke, do you have any ideas about why the process for a running remote service sometimes isn't included in `getRunningAppProcesses`?

Comment: I just tested Xposed v74 for Lollipop on my Sony Xperia M running Cyanogenmod 12.1, and the code in this answer worked fine.

Comment: We saw it two years ago or so in crash reports, so it could have been fixed in Xposed so that you're allowed to read your own process information.

Comment: may get unexpected process name with unreadable char.   we should use 'ActivityManager#getRunningAppProcesses' api

Comment: I just found that the ACRA library does this using `"/proc/self/cmdline"` instead of `"/proc/" + Process.myPid() + "/cmdline"`. Anyone know if one approach is safer than the other?

Answer (score 5):

To wrap up different approaches of getting process name using Kotlin:

**Based on the https://stackoverflow.com/a/21389402/3256989 (*/proc/pid/cmdline*)**:

```
    fun getProcessName(): String? =
        try {
            FileInputStream("/proc/${Process.myPid()}/cmdline")
                .buffered()
                .readBytes()
                .filter { it > 0 }
                .toByteArray()
                .inputStream()
                .reader(Charsets.ISO_8859_1)
                .use { it.readText() }
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            null
        }
```

**Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/55549556/3256989 (*from SDK v.28 (Android P)*)**:

```
  fun getProcessName(): String? = 
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.P) Application.getProcessName() else null
```

**Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/45960344/3256989 (*reflection*)**:

```
    fun getProcessName(): String? =
        try {
            val loadedApkField = application.javaClass.getField("mLoadedApk")
            loadedApkField.isAccessible = true
            val loadedApk = loadedApkField.get(application)

            val activityThreadField = loadedApk.javaClass.getDeclaredField("mActivityThread")
            activityThreadField.isAccessible = true
            val activityThread = activityThreadField.get(loadedApk)

            val getProcessName = activityThread.javaClass.getDeclaredMethod("getProcessName")
            getProcessName.invoke(activityThread) as String
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            null
        }
```

**Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/19632382/3256989 (*ActivityManager*)**:

```
    fun getProcessName(): String? {
        val pid = Process.myPid()
        val manager = appContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as? ActivityManager
        return manager?.runningAppProcesses?.filterNotNull()?.firstOrNull { it.pid == pid }?.processName
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an update to David Burström's answer. This can be written far more concisely as:

```
public String get() {
  final File cmdline = new File("/proc/" + android.os.Process.myPid() + "/cmdline");
  try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(cmdline))) {
    return reader.readLine();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please note that your snippet is assuming that there will be no arguments to the process. That's why my code snippet checks for null characters: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html

Answer (score 4):

I have more efficient method, you don't need IPC to ActivityManagerService and poll the Running process, or read the file.You can call this method from your custom Application class;

```
 private String getProcessName(Application app) {
    String processName = null;
    try {
        Field loadedApkField = app.getClass().getField("mLoadedApk");
        loadedApkField.setAccessible(true);
        Object loadedApk = loadedApkField.get(app);

        Field activityThreadField = loadedApk.getClass().getDeclaredField("mActivityThread");
        activityThreadField.setAccessible(true);
        Object activityThread = activityThreadField.get(loadedApk);

        Method getProcessName = activityThread.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getProcessName", null);
        processName = (String) getProcessName.invoke(activityThread, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return processName;
}
```

ActivityManagerService is already send the process infor to ActivityThread when process is start.（ActivityThread.main-->attach()-->IActivityManager.attachApplication--IPC-->ActivityManagerService-->ApplicationThread.bindApplication)

```
ApplicationThread:
public final void bindApplication(String processName,***) {
    //***
    AppBindData data = new AppBindData();
    data.processName = processName;
    //**
}
```

When we called getProcessName, it will finally deliver to AppBindData object.
So we can easily and efficient get current process name;

Answer (score 2):

First, get the current process pid. Second, list all processes of running. Finally, if it has equal pid, it's ok, or it's false.

```
public static String getProcessName(Context context) {
    int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> infos = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    if (infos != null) {
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : infos) {
            if (processInfo.pid == pid) {
                return processInfo.processName;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 2):

Since Android Pie (SDK v28), there is actually an official method for this in the *Application* class:

`public static String getProcessName ()`

[See the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application#getProcessName())

Comment: Nice find! I've done a comprehensive write-up about this approach in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55842542/238753).

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question correctly, you should be able to use [ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html), as per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542326/android-how-to-get-the-processname-or-packagename-by-using-pid).

Comment: Thanks I get processName with `AcitivityManager` and `android.os.Process.myPid()`

Answer (score 1):

There is a method in [ActivityThread class](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java#1658), You may use reflection to get the current processName. You don't need any loop or tricks. The performance is best compares to other solution. The limitation is you can only get your own process name. It's not a big deal since it covers most usage cases.

```
    val activityThreadClass = XposedHelpers.findClass("android.app.ActivityThread", param.classLoader)
    val activityThread = XposedHelpers.callStaticMethod(activityThreadClass, "currentActivityThread")
    val processName = XposedHelpers.callStaticMethod(activityThreadClass, "currentProcessName")
```

Comment: Nice find! Note that the method is called `currentPackageName()` prior to API 18. I've done a comprehensive write-up about this approach in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55842542/238753).

Answer (score 0):

The main process's father process should be zygote, this should be the accurate solution

1. first judge the process's name from /proc/pid/cmdline which should equal to package name
2. judge the process's father whether Zygote（why do this? because some APP have different processes with same name）