# Execute shell commands in same process of your app

Tags: android, shell, process

I'm trying to unmount and mount USB devices programmatically. I can do it in adb with these commands:

```
umount /mnt/usb1
mount -t vfat -o rw /dev/block/sdb /mnt/usb1
```

But when I try to execute these commands from my app it doesn't work. Here is the codes I use:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                    new String[] { "/system/xbin/su", "-c",
                            "umount /mnt/usb1" });
proc.waitFor();

Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {
              "/system/xbin/su", "-c",
              "mount -t vfat -o rw /dev/block/sdb /mnt/usb1" });
pr.waitFor();
```

Description of exec() method says: "Executes the specified command and its arguments in a separate native process. " So I think that command works but in a different process. In the process which my app runs, nothing gets effected. So I want to execute these commands in the process that my app runs.

I can get the process ID, thanks to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19631894/is-there-a-way-to-get-current-process-name-in-android) . Is there a way to use this process ID to call current process and execute shell commands?

Comment: Hi, did you get to solve it programatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is not possible, Because : `can you execute the command to kill the process from the same process` . So that will not be possible at this time,May be they will extend the `Process` to include limited restrictions.