# Xposed - How to get the package name of a process

Tags: android

I'm building an xposed module and i want to hook a method only if certain process (app) called this method.
I can get the process pid and uid using Binder, but I can't find a way to get the package name without having a context (i'm running my code in a class that can't get any Context as parameter).

How can I get it?

Thanks,
Gidi

Comment: This could resolve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542326/android-how-to-get-the-processname-or-packagename-by-using-pid

Comment: Thanks, but now i see that i didn't mention that i don't have any context to get the package manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution working for me in the case you don't have `Context`:

```
BufferedReader cmdlineReader = null;
try {
    cmdlineReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream(
            "/proc/" + android.os.Process.myPid() + "/cmdline"),
        "iso-8859-1"));
    int c;
    StringBuilder processName = new StringBuilder();
    while ((c = cmdlineReader.read()) > 0) {
        processName.append((char) c);
    }
    return processName.toString();
} finally {
    if (cmdlineReader != null) {
        cmdlineReader.close();
    }
}
```

Source: [Is there a way to get current process name in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19631894/is-there-a-way-to-get-current-process-name-in-android)