# Global application object instantiated twice android

Tags: android

I am instantiating an application object in the manifest file as below.

```
    <application android:name=".MyApp"
    android:icon="@drawable/add_icon_with_oval"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:process="com.test.myprocess"
    android:allowBackup="false">
```

I am starting a service from my application which is running in another process. This service is also declared in my manifest file as below.

```
     <service
        android:name="com.test.package.MyService"
        android:permission="some.permission"
        android:process="com.test.anotherprocess" >
    </service>
```

The problem that I am seeing here is that MyApp is instantiated twice, one for my process, com.test.myprocess and another instance for  com.test.anotherprocess.

Is there is a way that I can prevent creating MyApp for com.test.anotherprocess

Comment: No because the service needs an Application to run and a single Application can't be shared across different process. Maybe you should just start your service in the same process as your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there is a way that I can prevent creating MyApp for com.test.anotherprocess

you cannot, system will will create Application instance for each process. If you have some initialization code in your custom Application class then you can check process name and for example skip it, see code here: [Is there a way to get current process name in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19631894/is-there-a-way-to-get-current-process-name-in-android).

Answer (score 2):

Since the `service` is a component of `application`, it can't run without an `application`. The only way to have a single instance of your `Application` object is to remove the `android:process` attribute from your service.
For more details, check: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html#proc