# Detecting Application class running on main process on a multiprocess app

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, java-threads, multiprocess

I have an Android app that extends the `Application` class and has many app components (services, activities and broadcast receivers) running along three different process.

Each process will instantiate the `Application` class as soon as it is started. So I've been looking for how can I check inside the `Application` class code, if the instance is owned by the main app process but I have not been able to find it anything.

My manifest looks like this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="...">
        ...
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="...">
        ...
    </activity>

    <service android:name="..." >
    </service>

    <service android:name="..."
        android:process=":SecondProcess" >
    </service>

    <service android:name="..."
        android:process=":ThirdProcess" >
    </service>
```

Next is my `Application` class implementation:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        if (is this instance being ran on the main process?) {
            // Do something
        }
    }

}
```

Does anyone know how to check if the instance is running on the main process?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get current process name in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19631894/is-there-a-way-to-get-current-process-name-in-android)

Comment: @Nachi clearly not a duplicate since the focus of both of them is different. One is a mere approach than can be used in the other.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for the answer for the same question.

So far what i found is use can find the current running process from the process id and put a if check in onCreate.

```
 public void onCreate(){
 ...
 String processName = getProcessName();
 switch(processName){
    case process1:
         // do something 
         break;
    case process2:
         // do something 
         break;
    ....

 }
```

Comment: There is no `getProcessName()` method on the `Application` class.

Comment: yes there is no direct method but you can find the process name..
check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19631894/is-there-a-way-to-get-current-process-name-in-android